# How do I display the result of the beautifulsoup4 parser in django templates?

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a web application that collects jobs for programmers. It uses django 2.2 and beautifulsoup4.

I try to display the results of parsing on the screen after clicking the button in the form redirects to the page of the result of parsing (None). There may be an error in parser or views.py, I can't figure it out.

Logic:
1. Django displays the form on the main page
2. The user presses the button in the form
3. Parser collects data
4. Parsing result is displayed on the screen

workua.py - scraper

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def clean_description(s):
    return s.split('\n')[1]


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_data(html):
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    job_list = bs.find('div', id='pjax-job-list').find_all('div', class_='card card-hover card-visited wordwrap job-link')

    for item in job_list:
        title = item.find('h2', class_='add-bottom-sm').text
        company = item.find('b').text
        d = item.find('p', class_='overflow').text
        descr = clean_description(d)
        url = 'https://www.work.ua' + item.find('h2', class_='add-bottom-sm').find('a').get('href')

        data = {'title':title, 'company':company, 'descr':descr, 'url':url}

        # print(data)


def main():
    pattern = 'https://www.work.ua/ru/jobs-kyiv-python/?page={}'

    for i in range(0, 3):
        url = pattern.format(str(i))
        get_data(get_html(url))
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .workua import *
from .forms import PageForm

def index_page(request):
    form = PageForm(request.GET)
    return render(request, 'page/index_page_form.html', context={'form':form})

def workua_result(request):
    result = main()
    return render(request, 'page/workua_result.html', context={'result':result})
```

index_page_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Main page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 <form action="{% url 'workua_result_url' %}" method="GET" class="mt-5 mb- 
5 text-center">
     {% csrf_token %}

     {{ form }}

     <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Go</button>
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('', index_page, name='index_page_url'),
    path('workua/', workua_result, name='workua_result_url'),
]
```

workua_result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Work.ua result
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ result }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The problem isn't Django - you're not passing data back from main to be processed in the template

Comment: Okay, thank you! But how do I fix it?

Comment: The whole thing really needs a complete rewrite and I'm not going to do that for you.  Have a go at it.  You need to change `workua.py` so it is passing the data back with `return WhateverYouWantToReturn` and within.  But `get_data` is also not returning anything to `main` so you'll also need to modify that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a parser in views.py and the problem is solved. 
Created an empty data list and added the data that I collected from beautifulsoup. Before rendering called the main() function and passed the list of data in the context.

views.py

```
def workua_result(request):

    data = []

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    job_list = bs.find('div', id='pjax-job-list').find_all('div', class_='card card-hover card-visited wordwrap job-link')

    for item in job_list:
        try:
            title = item.find('h2', class_='add-bottom-sm').text
            company = item.find('b').text
            descr = item.find('p', class_='overflow').text
            url = 'https://www.work.ua' + item.find('h2', class_='add-bottom-sm').find('a').get('href')

            data.append({'title': title, 'company': company, 'descr': descr, 'url': url})
        except:
            pass

def main():
    pattern = 'https://www.work.ua/ru/jobs-kyiv-python/?page={}'

    for i in range(0, 4):
        url = pattern.format(str(i))
        get_data(get_html(url))

main()

return render(request, 'page/workua_result.html', context={'data': data})
```